# PHP Curl: Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get an Access Token on The Taboola Backstage API according to this documentation.

[Backstage API - Authentication and General API Usage.pdf](https://github.com/taboola/Backstage-API/blob/master/Backstage%20API%20-%20Authentication%20and%20General%20API%20Usage.pdf)

My Sample Code looks like this:

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

$post = array(
    "client_id"           => "secret"
  , "client_secret"       => "secret"
  , "grant_type"          => "client_credentials"
);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $ckfile );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "App Client" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://backstage.taboola.com/backstage/oauth/token/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

    $result=curl_exec ($ch);

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($result, $header_size);

    var_dump($header,$body);
```

If I run the code I get the error message. Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found. What iam missing, i send it with POST to the right endpoint. Have someone please a tip for me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like their documentation may be slightly off.  I was able to get a proper API response by posting to `/backstage/oauth/token` (no trailing `/`).  With the trailing slash it tries to pass you through to a different non-API URL.

Also, it's necessary to pass the POST array through [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) so that cURL doesn't do a multipart form post from the supplied array.  Since it's an API, there's no need to do anything with cookies.  I removed a few other unnecessary options as well.

Here is some code to get you started that worked for me:

```
$post = array(
    "client_id"           => "secret",
    "client_secret"       => "secret",
    "grant_type"          => "client_credentials",
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "App Client" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept: application/json',
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://backstage.taboola.com/backstage/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0);

$result=curl_exec ($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$response = json_decode($result, true);

if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
    // okay
    $access_token = $response['access_token'];
    var_dump($response);
} else {
    // error
    echo $response['error'] . ': ' . $response['error_description'];
}
```